# Estimates on Wikidata number of statements, items, properties and mapping to triples

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

I'm coming over from other knowledge bases to Wikidata. I have some questions on the terminology and size of Wikidata.

1. An RDF **Triple** contains a *Subject*, *Relation*, *Object*. Is there a one-to-one definition mapping to a Wikidata **Statement** containing an *Item*, *Property*, and *Value* ? I'm following the [description of its data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikidata).
2. Is there a definitive page showing how many statements, unique items, and unique properties it contains? I've only found [this Wikidata page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Statistics) which states there are about 87M items.

Comment: Did you mean anything specific by unique items and unique properties? I mean, each item and property are by definition unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (1), have a look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel/Primer and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format. A Statement is potentially much more than just subject, predicate, object, so the mapping is more complex, and many triples may be needed to describe a single statement.

For (2), there are public Graphana dashboards providing detailed analytics. However, there are too many dashboards with too many details, it seems https://grafana.wikimedia.org/dashboards/f/k0zbgDsik/wikidata-dashboards. For statements, I found https://grafana.wikimedia.org/d/000000175/wikidata-datamodel-statements?orgId=1&refresh=30m which sais that there are 1.1 billion statements on Wikidata. For Items and Properties (collectively called "entities"), I found https://grafana.wikimedia.org/d/000000167/wikidata-datamodel?orgId=1&refresh=30m, which tells me that there are about 87 million Items and about 7500 unique Properties.